# MYSQL variable change when performing mysqldump

Tags: database, mysql, percona

I have a mysql db using innodb engine.  When I do a mysqldump the table is locked and writes will fail.  So I don't want to send writes to a db that is performing a mysqldump.

Is there variable I can look at that would indicate a dump is happening and the db is locked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no specific variable that indicates a mysqldump is in progress.  What is a mysqldump after all?  It's just a `SHOW CREATE TABLE <Table>` and `SELECT * FROM <Table>` for every table.  You can see these in SHOW PROCESSLIST.

For what it's worth, you don't have to lock anything as long as you're backing up only InnoDB tables.  Use `mysqldump --single-transaction` and it will use a transaction to ensure a consistent read for the backup process, instead of locking.

See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction

But to answer your question more directly, you can query a couple of places to discover current locks:

- [SHOW OPEN TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-open-tables.html)
- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCKS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locks-table.html)

---

Re your comment:

Reading from a database when you're using Percona XtraDB Cluster is still just a local read. It should be fine to use `mysqldump --single-transaction`.  It shouldn't be any different if you're using Percona XtraDB Cluster (btw, I work at Percona).

The only thing that might be affected by PXC is if you use `wsrep_causal_reads`, which makes reads block if there are uncommitted writesets incoming.

If you like Percona products, and you all your tables are InnoDB, you should use [Percona XtraBackup](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup), which also performs backups without locking.

Comment: Thanks Bill.  Ok I lied a little.  The database is actually a percona xtradb cluster.  The cluster has 3 nodes.  Will this still work?
I already have a script that checks the state of the cluster node, so I figured it would be easy to find a var that indicates a dump is happening.